# Для чего нужны классы

Tags: java

Возможно, глупый вопрос.

Есть у меня один большой класс - примерно четыре тысячи строк. Если я разделю его на несколько более мелких классов, даст ли это какое - то улучшение производительности? Что вообще даёт распределение кода на классы, кроме удобства его редактирования? Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы будете разделять логику между классами, то вас примут на работу

Comment: слишком много зависит от конкретного проекта и конкретной ситуации. Но сильно в производительности не потеряете, зато читабельнее станет.

Comment: вы вообще не должны думать о производительности в таких вопросах

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Основная идея модульного программирования состоит в том, что большая задача делится на меньшие относительно независимые подзадачи (принцип «разделяй и властвуй»). В развитии модульного программирования — объектно-ориентированном программировании — этот принцип выражается в создании множества объектов, каждый из которых решает только свою собственную задачу.

Используемый вами антипаттерн проектирования называется **Божественный объект**, Ваш обьект делает настолько много, что обычным объектам это не под силу. Будем считать что у вас там пречется некоторая **галактика**, и вообще весь остальной код это декорация над этим объектом :)

Подход «божественного объекта» противоположен принципу «разделяй и властвуй»: основная часть функциональности программы кодируется в одном объекте. Так как этот объект хранит большое количество данных и имеет много методов, его роль в программе становится «божественной» (всеобъемлющей).

В итоге мы имеем непереносимый и плохо тестируемый код, в котором, к тому же, сложно разобраться. Так же, подобный код довольно сложно поддерживать, учитывая, что вся система зависит практически только от него. Проблема в том, что вся программа настолько становиться зависима от этого класса, что внесение изменений или попытка исправления ошибки становиться через какое-то время настоящим кошмаром.

Тот минимальный выигрыш в производительности, которого может не быть совсем, не стоит того, чтобы держать весь код в одном классе и каждый раз переписывать огромную долю своего кода, чтобы подстроиться под новые бизнес-процессы.

Answer (score 4):

Всё просто. Люди видят вначале вокруг себя объекты, а потом уже действия, каким-либо образом связанные с этими объектами. ООП пытается повторить это восприятие человеком окружающего мира. Именно поэтому писать сложные программы проще используя ООП, то есть, используя классы, чем на функциях.

Если Вы в программе используете только один класс, то это равносильно написанию программы на функциях...

Comment: и встречный вопрос, а чем плохи программы на функциях?

Comment: Функциональщики читают этот ответ с умилением.

Comment: Если в программе 100 функций, наверняка их можно логически объединить в какие-то группы, то есть в классы

Comment: Удобнее запись: object->func(...), чем эта: func(object, ...)

Comment: @sitev_ru ...и некоторое общее состояние

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: Функциональное программирование, в отличие от процедурного, вовсе не исключает классы. Просто оно делает акцент на преобразованиях самих функций и immutable-структурах данных.

Comment: @sitev_ru, удобнее кому?

Comment: @Grundy, object.func(...) - тем самым показываем, что функция относится к этому объекту, разве не удобно?

Comment: @sitev_ru, неа, а если функция относится не только к этому объекту?

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: Если "функция" относится не только к "этому объекту", то нам помогут интерфейсы и их имплементации. Да и наследование с этим вопросом позволяет довольно наглядно разобраться: возможно "другой объект" - родственник "этого".

Answer (score 3):

Классы это некоторые абстракции из предметной области или реального мира. Они нужны для управления сложностью кода. Вполне можно обойтись без них (привет, процедурное программирование), но программа на каком то этапе становится слишком запутанной.

Не всегда удается разбить класс на несколько мелких классов. Т.к. принцип  `solid` никто не отменял.

По производительности трудно что то сказать, скорее нет, чем да. На нее совершенно точно влияет размер методов. Маленькие легко инлайнятся jvm.

Comment: SOLID - это пять принципов, и каким образом они мешают дробить класс - не очень понятно.

Comment: Первый принцип, Single responsibility principle. Если у нас есть класс автомобиль, мы не сможем сделать два класса. В первом из которых будут методы ехать, перевозить, а во втором классе методы ломаться и заправлять.

Comment: SRP как раз наоборот заявляет, что ломаться может что-то одно, что не заправляется.

Comment: интерфейсы Crushable, Rechargeable, Rideable, Carrying нам в помощь + имплементации в классах.

Comment: ваши замечания заставили задуматься. Хорошо, предлагаете создать некоторое множество интерфейсов реализация которых где будет? в одном классе? тогда не вижу здесь противоречия. Если же в разных, то это будет похоже на https://habrahabr.ru/post/251089/

Comment: Если в одном классе - почему бы и нет. Если в разных классах - кто запрещает классу Велосипеды не имплементировать интерфейс Заправляемый? Отправить посылку мы сможем и на велосипеде и на автомобиле (на последнем, наверняка, Почтальону будет комфортнее).

Comment: @DimXenon Речь не об этом. Создать интерфейсы и  один класс который будет их реализовывать никто не запрещает. Об этом я изначально и говорил. Весь поинт тут в том, что не всегда возможно раздробить класс на отдельные классы, т.к. получаются классы с непонятным назначением и абстракция при этом сильно страдает.

Comment: Если оно реально не делится - и не стоит его делить, понятное дело. Если приложение - это один класс Кота, который мяукает() и, например, ест(), то нам может и не понадобится, например, интерфейс Кормимое. Кот хочет кушать, и не нужно отделять эту его черту от его природы. Пока у нас в качестве питомцев не оказываются кот, шредер и ребёнок. Их всех бывает нужно покормить. Всё зависит от того, какой уровень абстракции нам удобно использовать в конкретной задаче. Бывают сложно дробимые классы, бывают классы, которые дробить и не нужно. В последних случаях нужно обеспечить красоту их структуры.